# JQuery How to select all anchors within current list item?

Tags: jquery

I wish to, using JQuery, show and hide some anchor tags as I hover over a list item.

How do you loop through the current anchors within a list item using $(this) ?

Here's what I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.currentlist > li').mouseover(function(event){
        // loop through each anchor tag within this list using $(this)
        // and add the .active class
    });
    $('.currentlist > li').mouseout(function(event){
        // loop through each anchor tag within this list using $(this)
        // and remove the .active class
    });
});


a .active
{
  display: block;
}

a.edit-icon
{
  display: none;
}

a.delete-icon
{
  display: none;
}

<ul class="currentlist">
    <li><a href="#" class="active">index</a><a href="#" class="edit-icon">edit</a><a href="#" class="delete-icon">delete</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="active">profile</a><a href="#" class="edit-icon">edit</a><a href="#" class="delete-icon">delete</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="active">contactus</a><a href="#" class="edit-icon">edit</a><a href="#" class="delete-icon">delete</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="active">findus</a><a href="#" class="edit-icon">edit</a><a href="#" class="delete-icon">delete</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.currentlist > li').mouseover(function(event){
      $(this).find('a').addClass('active');
    });
    $('.currentlist > li').mouseout(function(event){
      $(this).find('a').removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

Where `$(this)` refers to hovered `li` and `$('a', $(this))` context selector is used to find all links inside them and add/remove classes.

Comment: @Sarfaz - thanks - hopefully nothing is going wrong with my copy and paste but.. its not working.

Comment: @Sarfaz - I must be doing something stupid here's the actual code in two parts: <html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
a.active
{
  display: block;
}
a.edit-icon
{
  display: none;
}
a.delete-icon
{
  display: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

Comment: <ul class="currentlist">
  <li><a href="#" class="active">index</a><a href="#" class="edit-icon">edit</a><a href="#" class="delete-icon">delete</a></li>
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.currentlist > li').mouseover(function(event){
      $(this).find('a').addClass('active');
    });
    $('.currentlist > li').mouseout(function(event){
      $(this).find('a').removeClass('active');
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>

Comment: @Nicholas: You have added ` class="active"` to all links remove those classes and then see.

Comment: @Sarfaz - changed the order of the css and it works now - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) to shorten the events, [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to get the anchors and [`.addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) and [`.removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) to toggle `.active` on and off, like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('.currentlist > li').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('a').addClass('active');
  }, function() {
    $(this).find('a').removeClass('active');
  });
});
```

You'll want to use [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) here because `mouseover` and `mouseout` will fire when entering and exiting children, where `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` (which [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) uses) won't).

Also your CSS needs a fix, this:

```
a .active
{
  display: block;
}
```

Shouldn't have a space, it should be like this:

```
a.active
{
  display: block;
}
```

Also, it should be moved to the end so it overrides the `.edit-icon` and `.delete-icon` definitions.

[Here's a working version with all of the above changes](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/uPB24/).

Comment: @Nicholas - Are you still having issues after the fixes in this answer?

Comment: no its all good now. Thanks for the v. comprehensive answer via jsFiddle. I think JQuery questions must draw the fastest guns on the planet!

Comment: @Nicholas - I'm confused how the other answer resolved any of this issues I outlined here, but good luck.

Comment: it was my bad that stopped @Sarfraz's answer succeeding first. Once again thanks - I voted both up.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
$(event.currentTarget).find("a.active").removeClass("active")
```

should do it for you.